# Django add new item to dict

Tags: django

```
thread_list = thread.objects.select_related().filter(thread_forum_id = current_obj.id).order_by('-thread_date')
            for thread in thread_list:
                count = post.objects.select_related().filter(post_thread_id = thread.id).count()   
                thread.post = count
```

How do that?

```
thread.post = count
```

^

```
class thread(models.Model):
    mess = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    objects = thread_manager()
```

I want add new item to the list manualy.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want to set a new variable to your each `thread` object in your queryset, then your approach is right. If you want to add a new object to your existing queryset `thread_list`, then it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not well-written, but I believe what you are looking for is `annotation` ([docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)):

```
from django.db.models import Count
thread_list = thread.objects.select_related().filter(thread_forum_id=current_obj.id) \
    .order_by('-thread_date').annotate(post_count=Count('post_thread_set'))
# I'm just guessing this name: 'post_thread_set'
```

The returned value is not a list of dicts, rather it is a `queryset`, which is an iterable of objects. You can then access `post_count` as an attribute:

```
thread_list[0].post_count
```

Answer (score 0):

You way is good. 
But there is a conflict:

```
thread_list = thread.objects.select_related().filter(thread_forum_id = current_obj.id).order_by('-thread_date')
            for thread in thread_list:
                count = post.objects.select_related().filter(post_thread_id = thread.id).count()   
                thread.post = count
```

Your class have name **thread** and your loop have name like class. 
for **thread** in thread_list:

Just do that:

```
for threads in thread_list:
                    count = post.objects.select_related().filter(post_thread_id = threads.id).count()   
                    threads.post = count
```

or something like this. Just change loop - i add 's' at the end of a word